# An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip". java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with Eclipse Kepler after TestNG installation

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, eclipse-plugin, testng-eclipse

My projects in Eclipse Kepler were working just fine until I downloaded TestNG. Post TestNG download, I am unable to click on Run button for my code. after I click on run or even if I hover over on run the following error message is displayed.

> An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip". java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

If I uninstall testing all my scripts run. But as soon as I reinstall Testing the issue reappears

I have tried the following methods:

- Re-installing Eclipse
- Changing Workspace
- Restarting Eclipse
- Creating new projects
- Installing TestNg from Eclipse Marketplace as well as by Installing new software.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip". java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

### Root Cause

You are unable to click on *Run* button for your code or after you click on *Run*  when you hover over on *Run* you see the error because **the labels of these buttons are calculated depending on the *.java file in the active editor**. This issue can occur if *there are two jars with same classes* e.g.  (*`selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1`* and *`client-combined-3.9.1`*).

### Solution

So the possible solutions are :

- Use only single *Java Client* variant either *selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1* and *client-combined-3.9.1*
- Change all *inner classes* in the file (including static ones) from **private** to **default** access.
- Clean your *Projects* from your **IDE**.
- Use [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*
- Incase you need to uninstall *Eclipse* use [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) with *Moderate* scan.
- Reboot your *System*.
- Execute your *Tests*

  Here you can find here a detailed discussion on [**`"Compute launch button tooltip" error`**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=270446)