# Tool Tip error in Eclipse Kepler after TestNG installation

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, eclipse-kepler, testng-eclipse

My projects in Eclipse Kepler were working just fine until I downloaded TestNG. Post TestNG download, I am unable to click on the run button for my code. After I click on run or even if I hover over on run the following error message is displayed.

> An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip".
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

If I uninstall testing all my scripts run. But as soon as I reinstall Testing the issue reappears.

I have tried Re-installing Eclipse, Changing Workspace, Restarting Eclipse, Creating new projects, Installing `TestNg` from Eclipse Marketplace as well as by Installing new software.

Eclipse Kepler Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: `20140224-0627`

Java JDK `1.7`

Comment: Welcome to SO. See:  [Issue while execution in Eclipse Kepler after TestNG installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825463/issue-while-execution-in-eclipse-kepler-after-testng-installation)