# Before Installing TestNG ,My Eclipse was working proper.But after installing TestNG below exception is coming

Tags: eclipse, selenium, testng

After installing TestNG I get this error Message:

> An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch buttontooltip".

And If I uninstall Testng then it is working proper
Below Eclipse version:

```
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825463/issue-while-execution-in-eclipse-kepler-after-testng-installation) SO question?

Comment: Kepler.2 is pretty old (released on February 2014). Please upgrade to Eclipse Photon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue while execution in Eclipse Kepler after TestNG installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825463/issue-while-execution-in-eclipse-kepler-after-testng-installation)